# Запуск функции при нажатии кнопки django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

У меня есть модель, которая **при первичном запуске** открывает csv файл и сохраняет данные в базу данных. Я хочу вывести на страницу кнопку импорта данных в базу данных при нажатии кнопки. То есть каждый раз, когда я жму на кнопку, должна запускаться функция, считываться файл csv и данные сохраняются в базу данных. Как правильно и где я могу это реализовать?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
import csv


class Fertig(models.Model):
    RASSEN = (
        ('Araber', 'Araber'),
        ('Hispano-Araber', 'Hispano-Araber'),
        ('Cruzado', 'Cruzado'),
        ('Lustiano', 'Lustiano'),
        ('PRE', 'PRE'),
        ('Muli', 'Muli'),
        ('Esel', 'Esel'),
    )

    ART = (
        ('Fohlen', 'Fohlen'),
        ('Stute', 'Stute'),
        ('Hengst', 'Hengst'),
        ('Wallach', 'Wallach'),
    )

    AUSBILDUNG = (
        ('Ungeritten', 'Ungeritten'),
        ('Geritten', 'Geritten'),
        ('Hohe Schule', 'Hohe Schule'),
        ('Zucht', 'Zucht'),
    )

    ABSTAMMUNG = (
        ('Ja', 'Ja'),
        ('Nein', 'Nein'),
    )

    FARBE = (
        ('Falbe', 'Falbe'),
        ('Bucksin', 'Bucksin'),
        ('Schimmel', 'Schimmel'),
        ('Rappe', 'Rappe'),
        ('Schecke', 'Schecke'),
        ('Porzellanschecke', 'Porzellanschecke'),
        ('Fuchs', 'Fuchs'),
        ('Brauner', 'Brauner'),
        ('Champangne', 'Champangne'),
        ('Cremello', 'Cremello'),
        ('Palomino', 'Palomino'),
        ('Tigerschecke', 'Tigerschecke'),
    )
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=255)
    preis = models.CharField('Preis', max_length=255)
    telefon = models.CharField('Telefon', max_length=255)
    beschreibung = models.TextField('Beschreibung')
    anzeigenummer = models.CharField('Anzeigenummer', max_length=255)
    standort = models.CharField('Standort', max_length=500)
    online = models.CharField('Online seit', max_length=255)
    url = models.CharField('URL', max_length=1000)
    bild = models.CharField('Bild', max_length=1000)
    rasse = models.CharField('Rasse', max_length=255, choices=RASSEN, default='')
    alter = models.CharField('Alter', max_length=255, default=1)
    grosse = models.CharField('Grosse', max_length=255, default=100)
    geschlecht = models.CharField('Geschlecht', max_length=255, default='')
    art = models.CharField('Art', max_length=255, choices=ART, default='')
    ausbildung = models.CharField('Ausbildung', max_length=255, choices=AUSBILDUNG, default='')
    abstammung = models.CharField('Abstammung', max_length=255, choices=ABSTAMMUNG, default='')
    farbe = models.CharField('Farbe', max_length=255, choices=FARBE, default='')
    is_draft = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_index=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f'/{self.id}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Fertig'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Fertig'

with open('main/daten.csv', encoding='utf-8') as File:
    reader = csv.reader(File, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        _, created = Fertig.objects.get_or_create(
        name = row[0],
        preis = row[1],
        telefon = row[2],
        beschreibung = row[3],
        anzeigenummer = row[4],
        standort = row[5],
        online = row[6],
        url = row[7],
        bild = row[8]
        )
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Fertig
from .forms import NewAnzeigenForm
from django.views.generic import DetailView, UpdateView, DeleteView




def index(request):
    anzeigen = Fertig.objects.filter(is_draft=True)
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'anzeigen': anzeigen})


def fertig(request):
    fertigeanzeige = Fertig.objects.filter(is_draft=False)
    return render(request, 'main/ready.html', {'fertigeanzeige': fertigeanzeige})


class FertigDetails(DetailView):
    model = Fertig
    template_name = 'main/details.html'
    context_object_name = 'article'


class FertigUpdateDetails(UpdateView):
    model = Fertig
    template_name = 'main/create.html'

    form_class = NewAnzeigenForm


class FertigDeleteDetails(DeleteView):
    model = Fertig
    success_url = '/'
    template_name = 'main/delete.html'


def create(request):
    error = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewAnzeigenForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            error = 'Ooopps.. Fehler...'

    form = NewAnzeigenForm()
    data = {
        'form': form,
        'error': error
    }
    return render(request, 'main/create.html', data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему следующим образом:

в views.py создал функцию:

```
    def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        with open('main/daten.csv') as File:
            reader = csv.reader(File, delimiter=';')
            for row in reader:
                _, created = Fertig.objects.get_or_create(
                    name=row[0],
                    preis=row[1],
                    telefon=row[2],
                    beschreibung=row[3],
                    anzeigenummer=row[4],
                    standort=row[5],
                    online=row[6],
                    url=row[7],
                    bild=row[8]
                )
        return redirect('home')
```

Добавил в urls.py

```
    path('upload', views.upload, name='upload')
```

Вывел кнопку в HTML шаблоне с помощью:

```
    <form action="{% url 'upload' %}" method="post">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                   <button type="submit">Daten importieren</button>
              </form>
```

Теперь всё работает как нужно.

Comment: при тяжелой обработке будет блокироваться запрос

Comment: Красавчик от души! а как реализовать мониторинг выполнение запроса?

Answer (score 1):

##### Вариант 1

Выносите этот код в `management_command` и при нажатии на кнопку запускаете ее через `call_command('<command_name>')`

##### Вариант 2

Ставите `celery`, пишите таск для `celery` - запуск команды (см. вариант 1), и при нажатии на кнопку - создаете таск.

Не знаю, второй вариант лучше, так как не будет блокировать выполнение запроса, а на счет первого не уверен, может сейчас `call_command` уже не блокирует запрос